# Henry's Law Constant in Freon

Tags: solubility

I am a physics student trying to calculate some values for a project I am working on, and am confused about Henry's constant.

I want to dissolve certain noble gases into freon in a pressurized chamber with temperature control, and want to know some of the numbers ahead of time.

I have seen the equation for the constant: $$K=\dfrac{p}{c}$$

My question is this: Where do the solvent characteristics come into play? I don't see how using this constant equation would get me a different constant for say, argon, in water vs. $\ce{C3F8}$?

Comment: Why, they come into play in that constant K. You switch to another solvent, you'll have another K.

Comment: Also, $p$ is the partial pressure of the gas which is dissolving (which is distinct from the vapour of the liquid) and not the total pressure in the container.

Comment: To elaborate on another comment, it is better to write $K_{12}=p_2/c_2$ which makes explicit that K depends on the solute (subscript 2) and solvent (subscript 1) pair.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. As it turns out, Henry's Law seems to only be valid is the solvent is close to the density of water, so I will need to search for another method to solve this problem.